# How do I stop bots from triggering my bots commands?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a bot with some basic auto-responses. I have a separate bot with similar features and some shared auto-responses between the two bots. How do I block bots from triggering each other in discord.py?

My current code is this:

```
if discord.User.bot == True:
    return
```

That's placed inside my on_message() event, right at the start, after a check to see if the bot is the message triggering the event. This currently doesn't work. I'm new to the idea of importing stuff and using class systems so any help/clarification is useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to the class itself, not the instance

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return 

    # rest of the code here
```

Also this is only going to work on the `on_message` event, if you want it to work on commands you need to create a global check:

```py
@bot.check # or client.check,
async def is_bot(ctx):
    return not ctx.author.bot
```

Reference:

- [`discord.Member.bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member%20bot#discord.Member.bot)
- [global checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#global-checks)